# jQuery update image src on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't want the images to load until the link is hovered, so for that here is the script but it's not working, can someone help me in correcting it?
I added an event listener to each link, and on mouseover called a function that sets the image. To make things more interesting, we can copy lazyload a bit here and also use the data-original property :)

For example: this is the HTML
Code:

```
<li>
   <a href="#" class="tip_trigger">
      <img class="tip" alt="300 Grams"
              data-original="https://lh5.googleusom/-qCRpw.../300%2520.jpg"
              src='empty.gif' width="90" height="90"/>
      Alex
   </a>
</li>
```

Then, add an event listener:

Code:

```
// call for each element with the class 'tip' that's being hovered upon
$('.tip').hover(function()
{
   // retrieve the image inside this element
   var elem = $(this).find('img');

   // set the 'src' to the 'data-original' value
   elem.attr('src', elem.attr('data-original'));
});
```

for a live demo, you can see this page http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/04/testing-slidernav.html
the above part of script is only added to the first letter ALEX in 'A' Category.

Comment: How is it "not working?"

Comment: The live demo nearly crashes my browser because it uses JavaScript for all the effects. Have you ever heard of CSS3 transitions?

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Maybe you need a better browser/computer. ;)

Comment: @epascarello: No, that's not it :-)

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt well I think epascarello is not wrong about the browser idea.

Comment: @CryOfFaclon I'm sure that Firefox on a i5 (3.1 GHz) + AMD HD6970 should be fine. My point is simply that you shouldn't use a CPU-based technique (JS) when there's a GPU-based technique (CSS) available. All you're doing is making your website extremely inefficient, scaring off users, without any realistic gains.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Well maybe you are right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.tip` is already the image so you cannot find an image with `$(this).find('img');`

try instead

```
$('.tip_trigger').hover(function()
{
   // retrieve the image inside this element
   var elem = $(this).find('img');

   // set the 'src' to the 'data-original' value
   elem.attr('src', elem.data('original'));
});
```

use also `.data()` method instead of `.attr()`

Comment: WOW, you are a genius :) it works, can you tell me like if you are sure about it, that by doing this NO IMAGES WILL load until they are hovered? as I am scared to death if images still load even if it is not hovered

Comment: yes, the only way that those images have to be loaded is triggering the event (via javascript). So I strongly suggest you to think a technique to ensure accessibility when javascript is not enabled

Comment: Well I am not worried with that as I don't want the visitors to come who don't have javascript :) Now I am really really confused, If this much small script can make life easy WHY AM I USING LAZYLOAD, isn't there a script like this that do the same thing Just instead of hover it WORKS FOR SCROLL.

Comment: lazyload on scrolling is a little-bit different technique. :) Usually on scroll you load some images and then you soon show them as soon as they are ready. Here instead you load and wait a single image every time an `hover` occurs

Comment: Oh so it means I am left to lazyLoad :P I was asking because there is one annoying thing that lazyload is doing and I don't know what to do about it. I have done a post about it too but no one replied, If you don't mind can you have a look at it, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235372/cached-images-loaded-again-in-lazyload

Answer (score 1):

`var elem = $(this).find('img');`  <-- you are looking for an image when this is the image.

Either replace the element you attach hover to

```
$('.tip_trigger').hover(function()
{
   // retrieve the image inside this element
   var elem = $(this).find('img');

   // set the 'src' to the 'data-original' value
   elem.attr('src', elem.attr('data-original'));
});
```

or keep it the way it is and do not look for an image

```
$('.tip').hover(function()
{
   var elem = $(this);

   // set the 'src' to the 'data-original' value
   elem.attr('src', elem.attr('data-original'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bound the hover to the img element, therefor you can't find a img child. Just use this, or change the hover to .tip_trigger.

```
$('.tip_trigger').hover(function() // That should do the trick
{
   // retrieve the image inside this element
   var elem = $(this).find('img');

   // set the 'src' to the 'data-original' value
   elem.attr('src', elem.attr('data-original'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.find() searches children. You have already found the img with your ".tip"-selector.

```
var elem = $(this);
```