# Replace img attribute

Tags: jquery

I have the following img tag that is part of a larger HTML page. This is the first image tag in the document. I would like to change the first image (white.png) with the `data-original` attribute.

```
<img width="676" height="450"
     src="http://somewebsite/white.png"
     data-original="http://somewebsite/shutterstock_197488871-676x450.jpg"
     class="lazy attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="(Shutterstock*)"
/>
```

Here is the HTML

```
  <div style="font-size: 12pt; color: #ccc; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;"><span id="author">Natural News</span> | <span>Sat, 16 Aug 2014 13:06:21 PM</span>
</div>
<img width="676" height="450" src="http://somewebsiteimages/white.png" data-original="http://somewebsite/shutterstock_197488871-676x450.jpg" class="lazy attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="(Shutterstock*)" />
<noscript>
    <img width="676" height="450" src="http://somewebsite/shutterstock_197488871-676x450.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="(Shutterstock*)" />
</noscript>
```

Comment: Have you tried methods `.data()` and `.prop()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery update image src on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281210/jquery-update-image-src-on-hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation I chose was this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img')
    .first()
    .attr('src', $('img').first().data('original'));
});
```

I added a document ready function and create an anonymous function in that to do the work.  First I selected all of the 'img' elements and then using the 'first()' method we limit our method to just the first img element in the document.  Then we change the 'src' attribute of the image to the value of the 'original' location on the same 'img' element.

If you could refine the selector to use a class of the image like this you may also have better results

```
$('img.wp-post-image')
```

You could also change the jQuery selector to

```
$('img.wp-post-image:first')
```

and then you could remove the .first() function call.  Which would leave you with this in the .ready function:

```
$('img.wp-post-image:first').attr('src', $('img.wp-post-image:first').data('original'));
```

references:
[jQuery :first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)
[jQuery .data() method](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: How does that work exactly? Is there a place online where I can learn to understand that replacement logic?

Comment: @MajorAlanDutch - If I understand your question correctly then you are good with the jQuery selector logic that allows us to pinpoint the element you are targeting for the replacement.  And you are asking about how we are replacing the image.  To replace the image we need to change the 'src' attribute of the image.  To set a new src attribute value we need to call the attribute setter method - .attr( {attributeName}, {newValue}).  You may be more familiar with the getter method which looks similar.  Note: .attr, .val, .prop, .data, .css and others all support setting values in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

To get the image, you can use one of these:

```
var img = document.images[0];
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
```

And to change it, one of

```
img.src = img.getAttribute('data-original'); // old way
img.src = img.dataset.original;              // new way
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
var workingImage = $("img").first();
workingImage.attr("src",workingImage.attr("data-original"));
```

This search for the first image. Then, it changes the source by the attribute.